# Google Script Editor - Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)

Tags: google-apps-script

This was working yesterday and then just quit working today with the error "Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string).". Any idea why this is going on?

```
var today = new Date();
sheetArchive.getRange('X3:X3').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")); // date submitted
```

Comment: Is your script is deployed?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's anything wrong there.  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Break up your chained code into multiple lines for debugging purposes.  You can put it all back on one line after you've found the problem.  It might be an incorrect error message.  It could have been a temporary service disruption.  It could be a bug.  In any case, you'll need to get some more information.

Comment: Can replicate it too. Calling `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), x, y)` works, `Utilities.formatDate(today, x, y)` fails with the same error message.

Comment: It was stupid syntax error in my case. I accidentally called method without parameter and passed this empty param as formatDate() first param.

Answer (score 2):

Google must have had an error, I have not changed anything and then it started working again the next day.